# SQL query for top 100, displayed in reverse

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database of logos, 18K strong. Each logo has a score. I want to select the top 100 by score and display them from 100 to 1, not from 1 to 100.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbllogos WHERE status = 'live' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100
```

which works fine for selecting the top 100, but the php WHILE loop then displays them from 1 to 100. I can't figure out how to swap the order so it displays 100 to 1. Changing DESC to ASC obviously isn't the answer as that selects the 100 with the lowest scores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM tbllogos
      WHERE status = 'live'
      ORDER BY score DESC
      LIMIT 100
     ) t
ORDER BY score ASC;
```

Comment: Subquestion:) If I want to use pagination here, using an offset (20) in the query, it shows 20 to 1 on page one. How would I make that 100 to 80? I want 20 to 1 to be page five.

Comment: Ah, never mind. Did it in PHP with `if ($currentpage == 1) $q = "LIMIT 80, 20";` etc.

Comment: `from 100 to 1, not from 1 to 100` I'm very confused

Comment: @Strawberry, sorry if I explained it poorly. If you're a DJ playing the top 20 on the radio, you don't start with #1. You start with #20 so that listeners have a reason to stay tuned. Same thing here. It works beautifully on the web. User engagement and all that.